# Simulator architecture is unsupported by the application

Tags: ios, appium, appium-desktop

Appium Version  v1.18.0
Xcode Version.  9.4

used Appium Inspector for Automation Testing on iOS with capabilities
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6t06.png)

when Hitting on start session below error is occurred
Error
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/Applications/###.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the error message, it gives the answer:

```
Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/Applications/###.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode
```

You stated to have XCode 9.4 preinstalled and in Appium-Desktop you try to create sesion running imulator with iOS 11.4. It is simply not available in old XCode version you got.

You need to update your XCode and related tools to 11.x in order to run session with iOS 11.x simulator

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by following below steps .

I got this error when I was trying to run WebDriverio-Appium tests on my app built using XCode on real device [iPhone] which is connected to Mac. So my steps include install WebDriverApp on iPhone and adding correct Desired capabilities

Error Resolution Steps -

**[1] Uninstall appium and reinstall latest version** using below commands -

```
npm -g uninstall appium

npm -g install appium
```

**[2] Need this step if WebDriverAppAgent is not installed on real device .**

Make sure WebdriverAgent app installed on real device [iPhone / iPad] -
If you don't see WebDriverAppAgent [or IntegrationApp] on real device then you have not installed WebDriverAppAgent on real device. Follow below steps to install WebDriverApp on real device

[2.1] Clone WebDriveAgent from git on you local GitHub - https://github.com/facebookarchive/WebDriverAgent

[2.2]On Mac, using XCode, Open WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj to set up the runner before building.

[2.3] Select the Team and  provisioning certificate, that is trusted on the target device.

[2.4] Connect you iPhone to Mac on which XCode is available.

[2.5] Select your connected iPhone device from top menu. Eg. In screenshot ‘' is selected as  device.

[2.6] From Product menu select 'Build'. You need to provide Team name if not already provided to succeed build.

Once build is successful, run play button [ > ] which will push WebDriverAgent build to connected iPhone.

Integration App or WebDriverApp will appear on iPhone on success.

**[3] Desired Capabilities -**

Have accurate desired capability for appium in place. No need of appium.app as app will be installed on reaL device

```
// Example
// From iPhone’s Settings > General > About > Name
   "appium:deviceName": "My  iPhone Name",  
    
    // Click connected iPhone on finder and get iPhone’s 40 digit UDID 
 "appium:udid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
// From iPhone’s Settings > General > About > Software Version
 "appium:platformVersion": "12.5.7",    
 // Xcode > Your Project > “Signing & Capabilities”
"appium:bundleId":"com.XXXX.XXXX.myapp", 
    
//  https://developer.apple.com/account > Membership Details > Team ID
"appium:xcodeOrgId": "XXXXXXXXXX",  
"appium:xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer", // Default value
 "appium:orientation": "PORTRAIT",
 "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",

// Not needed for real device as app will be installed on iPhone
//"appium:app": "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dyanvksdsfdfggbgsyujn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app",
```

[4] Install you app on iPhone.
I build my app using XCode and pushed it to iPhone.